# Upgrading from netbeans 6.9 --> 6.9.1 on mac

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I want to upgrade from netbeans 6.9 to 6.9.1 on my MAC.

What steps should i take?

- Install 6.9.1 stand alone.
- Then delete 6.9.

  - Also how do you delete 6.9?  Just remove the application into the trash folder.

or is there a simple update process that doesn't require deleting version 6.9.

Also where's the best Netbeans MAC upgrade documentation?

Comment: This question should belong to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ no?

Comment: The installer leaves previous versions in `/Applications/NetBeans`.

Comment: look for related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190309/can-you-upgrade-netbeans-without-downloading-the-whole-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install 6.9.1; you don't have to delete 6.9 if you don't want to.

In your `/Applications` folder there is a `NetBeans` folder; in that folder you can have more then one version of NetBeans, since the version number is in the application name.

To uninstall, just delete 6.9 from the `/Applications/NetBeans` folder.

6.9 will not update to 6.9.1 from the NetBeans internal updater.

Comment: Make sure to run 6.9.1 BEFORE you delete 6.9 if you want to import your settings and code templates from previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Netbeans folder from Applications by dragging it to the Trash, and run the 6.9.1 installer.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the new Netbeans version. It will ask to import your settings/plug-ins of your previous install.

You also might want to vote for this Netbeans [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108684l). It is a feature request to upgrade your Netbeans using the installer.